# Tensorflow dataset loading for cycleGAN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to learn about GANs in tensorflow by using the keras cycleGAN tutorial. I am struggling with just loading my own images, same size etc. There it is done like this:

```
# Load the horse-zebra dataset using tensorflow-datasets.
dataset, _ = tfds.load("cycle_gan/horse2zebra", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_horses, train_zebras = dataset["trainA"], dataset["trainB"]
test_horses, test_zebras = dataset["testA"], dataset["testB"]
```

But i can't figure out how to do just that for my own images inside a folder on my pc. Typically i have so far used image_dataset_from_directory and there i'd just create a subfolder for the categories. I even tried loading them separately like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory

train_horses  = image_dataset_from_directory('horses', 
                                        color_mode="rgb", 
                                        image_size = (286,286),
                                        batch_size=1,
                                       )

train_zebras  = image_dataset_from_directory('zebras', 
                                        color_mode="rgb", 
                                        image_size = (286,286),
                                        batch_size=1,
                                       )
```

but this leads to an error like this:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 3 for '{{node random_crop/GreaterEqual}} = GreaterEqual[T=DT_INT32](random_crop/Shape, random_crop/size)' with input shapes: [4], [3].
```

What am i doing wrong? It seems the shape is somehow different.

Comment: Is this your answer? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71704268/using-tf-keras-utils-image-dataset-from-directory-with-label-list)

Answer (score 0):

For those searching. This is how you do it

```
train_A = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str('trainingDataA/*'), shuffle=False)
train_B = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str('trainingDataB/*'), shuffle=False)

def load_images(path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(path)
    image = tf.io.decode_png(image, channels=1)
    label = tf.strings.split(path, os.path.sep)[-2]
    return image, label

train_A = train_A.map(load_images)
train_B = train_B.map(load_images)
```