# how to make x_train y_train from train_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: keras

```
train_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory = train_dir,    image_size = IMG_SIZE,    label_mode = 'categorical',    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,    shuffle = True,    subset = 'training',    validation_split = 0.15,    seed=42)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear . i tried to figure what you need and answered below .

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your actual question is but first you should understand what `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` is doing. The argument directory expects a string in form of your directory path. The argument `image_size` hands in the dimension of your images (e.g. `image_size=(100, 100)`).
In addition you can specify if your label_mode should be categorical or not via ``label_mode`.

The post here might also help you: [Using tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory with label list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71704268/using-tf-keras-utils-image-dataset-from-directory-with-label-list)

I hope that helps.